# Android Java Coding Errors, Need Assistance

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner coder trying to learn how to make android apps. I am using [these tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roulejuE6B8&feature=BFa&list=PL33384E9848C4F55E&lf=plpp_video) and I guess I have ran into an error.

Here is my text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="25dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etCommands"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Type a command"
android:password="true" />

<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 

<Button
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:id="@+id/Bresults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" /> 



<ToggleButton
android:layout_weight="80"
android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ToggleButton"
android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvresults"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:checked="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting an error next to where it says button. The error says:

> Multiple annotations found at this line: - Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".  - error:error parsing XML:not well-formed (invalid token)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the tag on your second Linear Layout `>`

```
<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"> <!-- here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The colorcoding in your post already highlights the issue. You forgot the `>` after the LinearLayout opening tag.

Comment: Looking at the colors always helps. In this case, they simply turned black.

Comment: yea, i see it now.  the eclipse software didnt make it turn black.  ty for the quick reply though.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is complaining that your xml is not [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling). If the IDE's errors are not clear enough, you try an online validator such as http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ .